# Not able to pass object with AngularJS to web backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Title says it all. I'm new to this so I'm sure it must be a simple mistake.
Here's the controller

```
    $scope.removeProduct = function(product){
console.log(product._id);
    var inData = new Object();
    inData._id = product._id;
    console.log(inData);
    $http({ url:"/api/deleteprod/", inData, method: "POST"
            }).then(function () {
                        console.log("got here");
                        var index = $scope.vehicles.indexOf(product);
                        $scope.vehicles.splice(index, 1);

            })


};
```

and here's the server side.

```
module.exports = function(app, mongoose, config) {

    app.post('/api/deleteprod', function(req, res){
                    console.log("in app post",req);
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url='mongodb://localhost:27017/seedsdev';
});
};
```

Obviously what I want is to pass the _id to the server so I can work with it, but when I output req it's about 50 pages long and has none of the info I wanted. Before it's passed the object can be seen to be fine fia console.log.

What's the rookie mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `$http`, you pass the `post` data with a `data` property. Currently you're passing an `inData` property. Change to this:

```
$http({ url:"/api/deleteprod/", data: inData, method: "POST" }).then(...)
```

**Update**:

On the server side, you'll need to make sure you have a JSON parsing middleware, like that from `body-parser`:

```
app.use(require('body-parser').json())
```

Once you are parsing the body using `body-parser`, you'll have a `req.body` property with the parsed JSON.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work. I've been reading/trying tutorials for hours.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work?" Is the `POST` not performed (check network tab in dev tools)? Is the server code not handling the request properly?

Comment: I still get 50 pages of gibberish in req. I tried outputing req.data and req.body as well but they came back undefined

Comment: Actually I'm an idiot. I just went to doublecheck and req.body works fine. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing are two below things.

1) Data in post request as suggested by @Jacob

2) A parser of Post param `body-parser`. //npm install body-parser --save
This will help you to parse the POST data in node js.

So code would look like

```
$scope.removeProduct = function(product){
console.log(product._id);
    var inData = new Object();
    inData._id = product._id;
    console.log(inData);
    $http({ url:"/api/deleteprod/", data: inData, method: "POST"
            }).then(function () {
                        console.log("got here");
                        var index = $scope.vehicles.indexOf(product);
                        $scope.vehicles.splice(index, 1);

            })


};
```

IN Backend

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
   module.exports = function(app, mongoose, config) {

        app.post('/api/deleteprod', function(req, res){
                        console.log("in app post",req.body._id);
        var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        var url='mongodb://localhost:27017/seedsdev';
    });
    };
```

Comment: I think what I'm really missing is a brain, see the comments on the other post.

Comment: Hehe happy coding :)